# Append div not being triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append, volusion

I'm trying to add a div right after the product's name by using append.

Here's the code I have:

```
var txt1 = "<div id='yotpo-bottomline-placeholder'></div>"; // This is the DIV
$('#v65-product-parent > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td > font').append(txt1);
```

The div is correctly being added right after the product's name. The problem is that this div was supposed to trigger the Star Rating Review widget. See below

[image]

When I add this div directly into the HTML code (before the Retail Price) it is being triggered. But I'm using Volusion so I have limited access to the HTML file that's why I need to use the append. See below

[image]

Help?

Comment: The issue is probably caused by the code that intialises the star rating widget needing the `.yotpo-bottomline-placeholder` element to be present in the DOM when the page loads. If you're adding after that point then you'll need to initialise it manually

Comment: You mean adding the appended DIV before the DOM? How?

Comment: You can't. My point was you need to initialise the stars widget *after* you've appended

Comment: So if I use the append script before the Star Widget JS, it would work?

Comment: Yes, although forcing that could be tricky, depending on how the widget has been created

Comment: Yeah, I can't make it work. :(

Comment: I was able to put it where I wanted with CSS. Couldn't use the append though. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

When you append the markup to the DOM, you are doing exactly that. Appending some HTML to the DOM.

It is likely that the star review JS you're using is triggered in the $(document).ready() event, however that appended markup does not exist in the DOM when that event is triggered.

You will need to initialise the star rating manually.

Comment: How would you do that?

Comment: I have no idea what star rating system you're using, so I cannot answer this question. However it is likely just a matter of calling the same function that is called in the ready event.

Comment: This should probably be a comment then, as it doesn't answer the question